# log4j floods my console

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j

This is the log4j.properties that i have in my app

```
log4j.rootLogger=B C
log4j.logger.A=INFO, A1
log4j.debug=false
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %C - %m%n

log4j.logger.B=INFO, A2
log4j.debug=false
log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.A2.file=PRIME-log.txt
log4j.appender.A2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %C - %m%n

log4j.logger.C=INFO, A3
log4j.appender.A3=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.A3.file=employee_pass_regeneration-log.txt
log4j.appender.A3.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A3.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %C - %m%n
```

I only want File appender so i only use that , but some how my console is always flooded with DEBUG messages which i have never used

> 8704 [http-8080-2] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
>   - Rendering view with name 'passIndex' with model null and static attributes
>   {}

I guess these are all system messages , but with these debug messages its really hard to debug actually  i mean i cannot find my own sysouts i tried log4j.debug=false but still i get these messages

Comment: Which container are you running this in?

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of debug messages ... in one particular file i had this

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

This used to send all DEBUG messages to console

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure the property files you're looking at is the one read by your application.

```
System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("commons-logging.properties").toString());
System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("log4.jeroen").toString());
System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("log4j.properties").toString());
System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("org/apache/log4j/Logger.class").toString());
System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("org/apache/commons/logging/Log.class").toString());
```

Then make sure your have the debug level in the root of your logger:
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout